# How to deserialize such json response?

Tags: c#, json

have such response:

```
[{
        "pic_50" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar50",
        "friends_count" : 41,
        "pic_hires_filed" : "http://content.foto.mail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_myphoto/h-43.jpg",
        "nick" : "самвел",
        "is_friend" : 0,
        "is_online" : 1,
        "has_pic" : 1,
        "pic_190" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar190",
        "referer_id" : "",
        "pic_32" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar32",
        "referer_type" : "",
        "last_visit" : "1385039467",
        "location" : {
            "country" : {
                "name" : "Россия",
                "id" : "24"
            },
            "city" : {
                "name" : "Тюмень",
                "id" : "1553"
            },
            "region" : {
                "name" : "Тюменская обл.",
                "id" : "280"
            }
        },
        "uid" : "11070260334392665635",
        "app_installed" : 1,
        "status_text" : "",
        "pic_filed" : "http://content.foto.mail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_myphoto/i-43.jpg",
        "pic_22" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar22",
        "pic_id" : "43",
        "age" : 49,
        "last_name" : "Кочарян",
        "pic_big" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatarbig",
        "is_verified" : 1,
        "vip" : 0,
        "birthday" : "11.11.1964",
        "link" : "http://my.mail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/",
        "pic_128" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar128",
        "sex" : 0,
        "pic_small" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatarsmall",
        "pic" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar",
        "pic_180" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar180",
        "first_name" : "Самвел",
        "pic_40" : "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/rogozina.zoya/_avatar40"
    }
]
```

How to deserialize it?

Comment: Mmm. Use some deserializer. ) E.g. JSON.NET. What have you tried? What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted for other answer (JSON.NET is probably the best option for most people), but personally I prefer

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

as deserializer. It's simple, in one file which can be included to your project. If you have some nonstandards in the format, you can easilly tweak it.

Answer (score 4):

With [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet):

```
var array = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var obj = (JObject)array[0];
var pic180 = obj["pic_180"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add reference of [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/) library to your project and try this code

```
ClassName obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(serializedJson);
```